# Javascript: Inside class constructor method, initiate object and access one of its keys' value in another key's value

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop, constructor

While defining a class, inside the constructor method, I am trying to access the value stored in `myKeyOne` for calculating the value that should be stored in `myKeyTwo` - however i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myKeyOne')`

I managed to access the value stored in `myKeyOne` for calculating the value for `myKeyThree` though, which is outside of `myObject`

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myObject = {
      myKeyOne: 1,
      myKeyTwo: this.myObject.myKeyOne + 1
    };
    this.myKeyThree = this.myObject.myKeyOne + 1
  }
}
```

My question hence - Is it simply not possible to access the value of one key of an object when calcualting the value of another key of the same object in a class constructor method, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The object is not created yet, you can't do that

Comment: `myKeyTwo: function() { return this.myKeyOne + 1 }` and then `obj.myObject.myKeyTwo()`